# dependency not found at runtime maven

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm new to maven and somewhat new to java. Tried google and related sources, but I didn't find one which resembled my situation.

Right now, I have maven project `X` and `Y`. `X` can be seen as a shared library with some utilities, `Y` is a simple `JFrame` with a `"hello world"` printed and a call to a static method in `X`.

I do a "run as `maven install`" on project `X`, I get a `"build successful"`. I add project `X` as dependency in project `Y` (using the pom-editor in Eclipse, browsing the repository and locating it). I do a "run as `maven package`" on project `Y`, I get a `"build successful"`. Upon running project `Y` either via `java -jar` or inspect the produced jar, project `X` is missing everywhere and I get a fancy class not found exception. Eclipse finds it and there are no compile errors in the source editor.

Why is it only working in the Eclipse editor and not as jar?

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.deployment.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.company.deployment.shared</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

Maven doesn't produce a combined JAR file for you. What Eclipse is doing is looking at the Maven configuration and adding all the required classes / jars to your classpath for you when it runs.

If you want to run your program from the command-line, you will need to add all the JARs manually to your classpath.

Alternatively, you could run your program [directly from Maven](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/) which should set up all your dependencies. There are a number of options depending on what you want to do, i.e. if it's an application which is meant to be run by an end-user you could look into the [one-jar Maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you take a look at the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).  This produces an "uber-jar" comprising your project and all of its dependencies.  It can also do other things such as setting the entry point class to make your JAR file an executable JAR.

Comment: Will have a look at it, thanx for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) helpful

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="maven" [-Dexec.workingdir="/tmp"] -Dexec.args="-X myproject:dist"
```

If your client can not download dependencies from maven m2 repo on the fly like behind firewall or no internet connection, then you also need to package the dependencies using [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) to copy all dependencies and [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/index.html) to assemble dependencies

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because Maven resolves dependencies when building your project, but doesn't put all the dependencies magically in your jar. You're supposed to run your app with all its dependencies in the classpath:

```
java -classpath X.jar;Y.jar com.foo.bar.Main
```

Or you have to customize the maven jar plugin in order to create an executable jar, as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html). And you may also use the maven assemby plugin to copy all your Y project's dependencies to the target directory, next to the generated Y.jar.

Comment: Forgive me if I find this hard, I come from a .net world and my sales dpt sold me a java project to do. But for some reason, maven only checks if dependencies are there but not adds them? Thanks for the tip on the executable jar, but as it is now, all depependencies remain missing... How can I package this in such a way that my customers can use it? I sure hope they don't need the command line for this...?

Comment: @Helfdane - the reason it doesn't put the dependencies into your JAR is that this would not be the right thing to do in most cases.  And for the cases where it is, there are a variety of plugins to do that.

Comment: You are not going crazy @Helfdane Java is completely broken relative to .Net, but remember that .Net was invented to fix all of the stupidity in Java, so what can you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The artifact produced in project Y contains only build results in project Y only, not including its dependencies.

If you want to build a JAR in Y, which u can execute directly, you can consider using assembly plugin.

For example, the easiest way to build a uber-jar for project Y:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-all-in-one-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
            ...
</project>
```

Apart from a normal artifact, an assembly which contains classes etc from dependencies will be created, which is suitable to be executed by java -jar

visit http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/  for more sophisticated usage.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Sacre already explained the basic problem well (there basically is just no information on where to find the X.jar embedded in your Y.jar).

Additionally you can also look at the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) (which can e.g. generate launch scripts for your Y project that already have the right classpath set) and/or the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) (which you can use to e.g. directly launch Y with the right classpath using maven).